# Check if value is acceptable by SQL Server as Money before updating

Tags: c#, sql-server, currency

I would like to insert a string value into a database of column type `VARCHAR`. But before that I want to make sure if this value is accepted if the datatype was `MONEY`, too.

Is there a way to check if the value is compatible with `MONEY` type on SQL Server? I found this function:

```
public static decimal ValidateMoney(string ParMoney)
{
    decimal result;
    Decimal.TryParse(ParMoney,
        NumberStyles.Currency,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        out result);
    return result;
}
```

This function uses `CurrentCulture`. But still I see that it misinterprets `1,200` and `1.200`.

So how can I be sure if this value will be accepted by SQL Server as `Money`?

Comment: Don't. If you want to store a decimal value, use a decimal field type. Storing a decimal value to a text field is a very serious bug that can never be covered up by validations or reformats. As for the `money` type, it's better to use `decimal` with a specific precision. `money` is equivalent to `decimal(19,4)`

Comment: I'd like to add to what @PanagiotisKanavos wrote: Keep in mind that you don't know how long your application will exist, or how it might change in the future; it might grow in ways you would not imagine right now, so it is vital to design things as well as possible from the start, or at least keep things flexible, and this is the problem with DB-stuff: While your can generally refactor code, changing a database and it's structure is harder, as it will tend to include historic data, which you won't want to mess with, so do yourself a favor and use the correct format from the start if possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Makes sense what you say!

Comment: @Kjartan Will do that. Thanks! Sounds reasonable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, just a note. `money` is not equivalent to `decimal(19,4)`. They are stored differently and use different number of bytes on disk. Arithmetic operations, such as division, can produce different results.